# Getting started with python issues

Tags: php, python, debugging, variable-assignment

So, I just started with python and have learned how to fix some issues but I got stuck with this one and what I have searched, doesn't help me.

This is my `test.py` file: http://pastebin.com/TzASyCxm where I work with mysql and output some data to an LCD screen.

Right now, executing the code in my script returns the following error:

```
self.ip[host] = socket.gethostbyname(host)
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I'm trying to do like a simple, in php:

```
$data = array();
$test = 'level1';
$data[$test] = 'alex';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in PHP, where you need to initialize the variable `$data` with an empty array `array()`, so as to index and assign elements to it, in similar ways, you need to assign a dictionary to `self.ip` to subsequently index and assign values.

The ways you can do it varies with requirement, but we generally stick to one of the two formats

```
self.ip = dict()
self.ip = {}
```

**Note**

Python Error Messages are self explanatory and you can easily identify the Issue from it

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

It means `self.ip` is a string object, and in Python, String Objects are immutable and cannot be indexed unlike C/C++. So likely, you may have initialized this variable somewhere prior to the failure with a string.

Comment: yea... dumb of me, the message is obvious. Thanks

Comment: @w0rldart: If this or the other answer helped, consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, `self.ip` is a string, and you can't assign to elements within a string.

Presumably you meant to initialize it to a dictionary: `self.ip = {}`